# Haskell: list comprehension: Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [t]

Tags: haskell

When I am trying to run following function, I am getting error.

```
Prelude> let squareSum list = [result | (x, y, z) <- list, result <- x^2 + y^2 + z^2] 

<interactive>:4:5:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [t]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘squareSum’ has the inferred type
     squareSum :: forall t. Num [t] => [([t], [t], [t])] -> [t]
```

Can some one explain me, How to fix this? What is this error conveying exactly?

Comment: it's probably because you try to *draw out*  `result` from a *sum* - I guess you wanted `let squareSum list = [ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 | (x, y, z) <- list]`?

Comment: Thanks Carsten. I tried, but still facing same issue.      Prelude> let squareSum list = [ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 | (x, y, z) <- list]
Prelude> squareSum [1, 2, 3]

<interactive>:33:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (t, t, t)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall t. (Num t, Num (t, t, t)) => [t]

Comment: because the way you defined it with your tuple in the first place you have to call it like `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]`

Comment: to get your *example*  working use `let squareSum xs = sum [ x^2 | x <- xs]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Original Question

You posted:

```
Prelude> let squareSum list = [result | (x, y, z) <- list, result <- x^2 + y^2 + z^2]

<interactive>:3:5:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [t]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘squareSum’ has the inferred type
      squareSum :: forall t. Num [t] => [([t], [t], [t])] -> [t]
```

This is coming from the inference that is the computation `x^2 + y^2 + z^2` must be a list, due to using it as a source of values in a list comprehension (`result <- ...`).  And if that is a list, then the mathematical operators are over list typed value, which means your initial variables, `list` must be a list of tuples of lists (`[([t],[t],[t])]`) and each list must in some way be valid numbers (`Num [t]`).

## Comment Question

```
Prelude> let squareSum list = [ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 | (x, y, z) <- list]
Prelude> squareSum [1,2,3]

<interactive>:9:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (t, t, t)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall t. (Num t, Num (t, t, t)) => [t]
```

Now you say that the variable `list` contains tuples (`(x, y, z) <- list`) but then you define list as `[1,2,3]`.  To satisfy both, the numeric literals of `1`, `2` and `3` must represent tuples, which is possible if you defined a class instance `Num (t, t, t)`.

## What You Want

Carter already told you the solution, but you didn't apply it to a sensible list.  How about we define a solution and give it an explicit type so there is less confusion!

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let squareSum :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> [Int]
Prelude|     squareSum list = [ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 | (x, y, z) <- list]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> squareSum [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
[14,77]
```

Success!  We provided two tuples and get two Int results, yay!

Answer (score -1):

Following snippet solved my problem.

```
Prelude> let processData fun list = [y | x <- list, let y = fun x]
Prelude> let sumSquare (x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
Prelude> 
Prelude> processData sumSquare [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
[14,77]
```